# Use terminal-based documentation effectively (no web browser)

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, man

## The problem

I was trying to find shell scripting information without an Internet connection, i.e. via `man` page.
Specifically, I was looking how to pass and use *parameters*.

`man bash` does not contain all I need ([shell-scripting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Scripts) is missing).

Incidentally, browsing the Internet, I found out that I want to read the *Bash Reference Manual* (and yes, I have already found all I need online).

The same result could have been achieved by looking at the end of the `man` page, where one can find the following section:

```
SEE ALSO
       Bash Reference Manual, Brian Fox and Chet Ramey
       The Gnu Readline Library, Brian Fox and Chet Ramey
       The Gnu History Library, Brian Fox and Chet Ramey
       Portable Operating System Interface (POSIX) Part 2: Shell and Utilities, IEEE
       sh(1), ksh(1), csh(1)
       emacs(1), vi(1)
       readline(3)
```

The first item, `Bash Reference Manual` is actually what I want to read. How do I navigate through that link? Where do I find the rest of the documentation?

It looks like one has to rely always on the Network for retrieving meaningful information. Please, enlighten me with the `man` way. There must be something I am missing.

Comment: Not really a valid question.  But as a middle-aged man (see http://www.hulu.com/watch/278938), I can say that way back when, we DID use man pages.  But even then, say 20-30+ years ago, there WAS the Internet, and people used news groups instead of all this new-fangled tweetering.

Comment: OK, but, say you'd like to script something (I was actually looking for how to send parameters to my script), how would someone find that information without an Internet connection?

Comment: No internet = buy-a-book.  The manpages are not intended as how-to tutorials but as a reference for the details of commands, libraries, devices, etc.

Comment: I learned from books, Usenet, and lots of practice (otherwise known as trial and error).

Comment: What is your question, How do people learn or How do I find out about shells scripting ? Granted, the manual pages are not the best tutorials, however all the information is there, and incidentally it is how I leaned. It takes effort, but it is possible. Please, what is your question ?

Comment: @XTian: I found out the `SEE ALSO` section (that answers the 'how people learn'). Now I've to figure out how to navigate there.

Comment: According to `info` the first link in the Bash man page, on Ubuntu, is the one to POSIX one (fourth line down). I believe that he “Bash Reference Manual” is not a link.

Comment: @forquare, what does 'According to `info` the first link in the Bash man page is the one to POSIX one' mean? `info` is something like `man`... but the rest is obscure.

Comment: @roaima, would you mind removing the hold? Cheers.

Comment: I can nominate for reopening but, just as for putting on hold, it has to be a community decision

Comment: @XTian, would you mind nominate the re-edited question for reopening? Cheers.

Comment: @vonbrand, would you mind nominate the re-edited question for reopening? Cheers.

Comment: @cuonglm, would you mind nominate the re-edited question for reopening? Cheers.

Comment: @G-Man, would you mind nominate the re-edited question for reopening? Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a debian system, the `Bash Reference Manual` is in the `bash-doc` package.  It's probably similarly packaged in other distros.

The `The Gnu Readline Library` and `The Gnu History Library`
manuals are both in the `readline-doc` package.

You can read them with `info`, but IMO `info` itself is ghastly and almost unusable, with a terrible user interface - `pinfo` is a better alternative: `apt-get install pinfo` on debian-based systems.

e.g. `pinfo bash` or `pinfo history`

`info` navigation works in some inscrutable fashion.

`pinfo` navigates info docs in a manner similar to a text-mode web-browser like `lynx`.  Amongst other benefits, forward and back keys actually work as expected.

The `pinfo` project page, including access to source code, is at https://alioth.debian.org/projects/pinfo/

`Portable Operating System Interface (POSIX) Part 2: Shell and Utilities` is a for-sale .PDF document available from http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6880751&filter%3DAND%28p_Publication_Number%3A6880749%29 (this is dated 1993) - but you can also find a 2007 draft PDF of the spec at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n4217.pdf and probably many other places.  Newer versions may also be available, these were just the first I found with google.

Comment: +1 for calling `info` what it is, and learning me up about `pinfo`.

Comment: 1. How did you know about `bash-doc`? 2. OK, I've `sudo apt-get install bash-doc`, and then? 3. On Mac I could not find it via `brew`. Then, what is one expected to do / look for?

Comment: 1. by knowing my system well enough to know where extra docs are likely to be found. 2. if you have a mac, the `apt-get` command is worthless to you, it was only an example of how to install it on one type of system. 3. no idea, i don't use Macs very often...the Bash Reference Manual is definitely part of the bash source package, maybe see if there's an extra `make` target for building and installing the docs.

Comment: My bad, I was unclear. I installed it on my Ubuntu and I got it working. `info bash` will display the *manpage* if `bash-doc` is not present, otherwise will display *bash.info*. `vi` commands do not work in `info`... `pinfo` looks definitely better.

Comment: Let say I do not have your deep knowledge, yet, about my system. I do see from `SEE ALSO` that there is further material to read. How would you go find out that magic `bash-doc` package you mentioned? Where did you built your knowledge? Is a web browser mandatory for the task?

Comment: from years of experience that's impossible to distil into a sentence or two.  part of that experience includes knowing that on debian (and derivatives like ubuntu) extra documentation is often found in `-doc` packages  - e.g. `bash-doc`, `gcc-doc`, `sqlite3-doc`, `wireshark-doc` and many others.

Comment: sometimes those extra `-doc` packages are `.info` docs (common for FSF programs), sometimes it's text or pre-formatted TeX or groff output, sometimes it's html or something else.

Comment: Try running `apt-cache search -n -- '-doc'` - on my debian sid system that lists over 3500 `-doc` packages.

Comment: Understood. On Mac the *info* file is already there. Unfortunately there is no `pinfo` available with `brew`. But I've just found out about [*Vinfo*](http://alx741.github.io/vinfo/) (which uses *Vim*). Do you think in your answer you could address how to find the other items in `SEE ALSO` (2nd, 3rd and 4th items)? Then I will accept your answer as best answer :) And thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @cas, I've just found the `install-info` command line, although it is said that it *does nothing, since info file installation is now done via triggers.*, whatever this means. Basically, I was trying to figure out if there was another way to get those `command-doc` you mentioned above, without expressly knowing about them.

Answer (score 0):

GNU tools tend to have skeleton manpages, and have detailed (as in "textbook detailed") documentation in form of info files. They can be browsed by use of the `info(1)` program, or `pinfo(1)`, or even from within emacs.